# Pass object[] into a function in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Is there a resource on how to pass in a `Object[]` as a parameter within a PowerShell function?

Both of these functions are cmdlets and they are being exported correctly, but I cannot see the `$Return` object in my second function.

Is something like the following needed?

*[ParameterAttribute.ValueFromPipeline Property (System.Management.Automation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.parameterattribute.valuefrompipeline)*

```
# Within PowerShell code

$Return = My-Function -Param "value" # $Return is of type Object[]
$ModifiedReturn = My-SecondFunction -Input $Return
```

Where this is my function definition:

```
function My-SecondFunction
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [Object[]]$Input
    )
    begin {}
    process
    {
        Write-Host "test: $Input" # Does not return anything
    }
    end {}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`$Input` is the name of an automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#input). Use a different name.

I recommend `$InputObject` as that is in common usage so it has a well-understood meaning, but usually that means you are accepting pipeline input as well.

Of course if there's a name that's more descriptive for this parameter, you should use that.

[I have submitted this issue on the PowerShell GitHub project suggesting that `Set-StrictMode` be modified to check for automatic variable assignment](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3061).