# Strange PowerShell behavior during Invoke-Comand

Tags: powershell-3.0

Was going to make console validation of user input in my script, but have met a strange behavior of PS, here is the script:

```
function Prompt
{
    param([string] $prompt, $validationScript)
    $rv = $null
    do
    {
        try
        {
            $input = Read-Host -Prompt $prompt
            $rv = Invoke-Command $validationScript -ArgumentList $input
        } catch
        {
            Write-Host "Invalid input, try again"
        }
    } while (!$rv)
    $rv
}

$xxx = Prompt -Prompt "Enter integer" -validationScript {[Convert]::ToInt32($args[0], 10)}
$xxx
```

Its working good while you enter invalid values, but when there is a valid integer, then it returns value and PS hangups. If i stop it in ISE, there thousands of "Invalid input, try again", just looks like the loop never ends but without calling Read-Host. What the problem ?

Comment: `$input` is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0). Do not redefine it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell pass object\[\] into function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899833/powershell-pass-object-into-function)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks for the help, but i've found a problem, its the name of function - prompt. If i rename it to something else, it is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now sure why, but the problem within the function name "prompt", if its renamed to something else all works good.

Comment: [`prompt` is a function in powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts) so you can't use it for your own functions